# Multiple Collision Detection in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a dynamic yellow SpriteNode in motion with a categoryBitMask and a contactTestBitMask and it's intended to collide with the static red rectangle SpriteNodes with their own categoryBitMasks and contactTestBitMasks.

I would like to call a function only when both the rectangles have been hit by the yellow sprite? Does anyone know how to do that? I currently have the following code below that I use to check for the collusion with one rectangle.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
        var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {

            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB

        } else {

            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }

        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == kYellowCatergory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == kRectangleTarget  {


            //self.functionToCall()

        } 

    }
```

[image]

Comment: If the ball hits the right block twice then hits the left block, do you still want that function to be called?

Comment: Yes. That will be still fine. As long as it hits both eventually. @0x141E